# How can i send mailable into schedule in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to send a mailable into schedule, but the mail is ommited when schedule is execute

```
$schedule->call(function () {   
 Log::debug("START TEST MAIL"); //this is write in log
 $result = Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')->send(new MailRecover('12345678aZ*'));
 Log::debug("END TEST MAIL, RESULT: $result"); //this is write in log
})->everyMinute();
```

i put the same lines of codes (the logs and the mailable) in a controller and work perfectly, but in the schedule (kernel.php) doesnt work (only write every minute the two logs).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [closure command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#closure-commands), add it to `routes/console.php`:

```
Artisan::command('send:email', function ($project) {
    Log::debug("START TEST MAIL"); //this is write in log
    $result = Mail::to('myemail@gmail.com')->send(new MailRecover('12345678aZ*'));
    Log::debug("END TEST MAIL, RESULT: $result"); //this is write in log
});
```

Then run it in scheduler:

```
$schedule->call('send:email')->everyMinute();
```